# Symfony 4 and DoctrineEncryptBundle - Where define yaml configuration?

Tags: php, symfony4

I am trying to encrypt data for a medical application that's how i found DoctrineEncryptBundle (https://packagist.org/packages/michaeldegroot/doctrine-encrypt-bundle)

I am still a rookie with symfony 4 and the documentation give the method for what seems to be previous Symfony version.

I already downloaded the bundle (composer require michaeldegroot/doctrine-encrypt-bundle)

For step 2 : "Enable the database encryption bundle"[What is explain in document vs what I did in SF4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSoW5.png)
Which seems correct.

Then, there is no config.yml in SF4 and I don't know where to define the configuration (encryptor class and the path to the key file).

This yaml =>

```
ambta_doctrine_encrypt:
    encryptor_class: Halite # or Defuse
    secret_directory_path: '%kernel.project_dir%'   # Path where to store the keyfiles
```

The documentation : https://github.com/michaeldegroot/DoctrineEncryptBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration.md

My files
Entity Patient (which i want to encrypt)

`

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Ambta\DoctrineEncryptBundle\Configuration\Encrypted;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PatientRepository")
* @ORM\Table(name="patient")
*/
class Patient {

 /**
 * @var string
 * @Encrypted
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $nom;`
```

The controller :

```
public function ajouterPatient(Request $request)
{

    $patient = new Patient();
    $form = $this->createForm(PatientType::class, $patient);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $patient->setNomsAffichage($patient->getNom()." ".$patient->getPrenom());
        $patient->setActif(true);

        $em->persist($patient);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('menu_patients');
    }
    return $this->render('Patients/ajouterPatient.html.twig', array(
      'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

I guess i should define something in service.yml like a link with the bundle but i don't know how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html) says the configurations have been moved to `config/packages/` dir. Have you tried to add the needed config to `config/packages/framework.yaml`?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question but for the people who still want to know where to define the configuration yaml file in Symfony 4 for this bundle, here is the answer I got it working with.

In the file `config/bundles.php`
Add at the end this line to define the Ambta Symfony bundle:

```
return [  
    ...
    Ambta\DoctrineEncryptBundle\AmbtaDoctrineEncryptBundle::class => ['all' => true]
];
```

Create a new yaml file in: `config/packages/orm_services.yaml`
Here you can put the configuration. For example:

```
ambta_doctrine_encrypt:
  encryptor_class: Halite
  secret_directory_path: '%kernel.project_dir%'
```